# how to Inject an EJB into a java class

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

I want to inject an EJB3 into a java class which is not an EJB.
these classes are both on the same server and application.

Is that possible ...and if yes ..then how ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you should supply more information about your work environment. The usage of CDI changes the whole specturm. You can inject it when you use CDI, otherwise you can only inject it into other EJB's and servlets (if your application server supports it).

Otherwise you can do a lookup using

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
MyEjb ejb = (MyEjb) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/myEjb");
```

You can supply a name in the @EJB annotation you supply together with your @Stateless/@Stateful annotation.

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name="myEjb", beanInterface=MyEjb.class)
public class myEjbImpl implements MyEjb{
   // code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject it, but you can make a lookup for that EJB:

Look here:
http://www.roseindia.net/ejb/ejb-lookup.shtml

During the deploymentprocess of your EJB you may see, the Name of your Bean.